# Need to fix html code of google stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I cannot make google stacked column chart work. On the website https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

they provide code to draw this kind of chart:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
        ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
        ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true,
      };
```

But I could not find full html code to test it. I tried:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var data;
     var chart;

      // Load the Visualization API and the   package.
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});


      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create our data table.


         var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
        ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
        ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
      ]);

        // Set chart options

      var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true,
      };


var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But no luck.
 Could somebody give me a full html code for this chart?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the only thing that is missing is the closing `}` on your drawChart function it should be placed before `</script>`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var data;
     var chart;

      // Load the Visualization API and the   package.
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});


      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

            // Create our data table.


             var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
             'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
            ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
            ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
            ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
          ]);

            // Set chart options

          var options = {
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
            bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
            isStacked: true,
          };


        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```